# Not able to append dynamically generated html to an id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to append a dynamically generated html to an id using jquery.Below is the code:

```
var requestHTML="<table>";
    for(i=0;i<=8;i++){
    requestHTML+="<tr><td>"+responseData.hotels[i+1].name+"</td></tr>";
}
requestHTML+="</table>";
$("#hotelList").append(requestHTML);
```

Below is the html code:

```
<body>
    <div id="hotelList">
    </div>
</body>
```

Html is generating properly but not getting appended.
Can anybody please help on this ??

Comment: your code seems to work fine. What is the exact error it throws?

Comment: Check if the stament `$("#hotelList").append(requestHTML);` is being called. try this in console and see if the div is appended with the table tag

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7fwzstr1/) . I would check if you really get collection of needed length. You might have less array items in `responseData.hotels` and if so an error is thrown.
Possible solution is to add something like `if (!responseData.hotels[i+1]) continue;` before code inside loop. A better solution would be to iterate not till `8` but `responseData.hotels.length` like [so](https://jsfiddle.net/7fwzstr1/2/)

UPD: if you want to get a length of `hotels` you should do smth like `Object.keys(responseData.hotels).length`. But this is not an issue. You need to ensure you get the data on the front end.
Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7fwzstr1/7/)

Comment: see no data in comment. Anyway, did you check that you really receive that data?

Comment: ok, I used your data and it works https://jsfiddle.net/7fwzstr1/3/ . Check if you really receive that data on the client